# mysql: i want to include a value in my row

Tags: mysql

i have a table, that has a lot of same values.
in my table i want to select distinct values based by column. my problem is including

this is my table

```
column column.a column.b
1      tax1     100
1      tax2     200
1      tax3     300
2      tax1     100
2      tax2     200
```

this is my select statement

```
        select distinct column, sum(column.b) - column.b as amount,
        (select column.b where column.a = tax2)as column.c
        from table order by column
```

i want to include in my select statement column.b where column.a = tax2

this is the output that i expect.

```
column amount column.c
1      500    200
2      200    200
```

i just don't know i can include it in my select statement. thanks.

Comment: Your results don't make sense (to me) given the sample data.  What is column c?  How is amount calculated?

Comment: I think I understand.  You are misusing SQL, by mixing aggregated values and non-aggregated values in the same `select`.  Your question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: What is `sum(column.b) - column.b` supposed to mean? There are 3 different values of `column.b` for column 1, which one is supposed to be subtracted?

Comment: it will sum colum.b first and subtract the 1st row of column.b

Comment: First row in what order? Should it use `column.a` as the ordering?

Comment: where tax1 is first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is to use conditional aggregation and an explicit `group by`.  For example a reasonable query would be:

```
select column,
       sum(case when a <> 'tax2' then b else 0 end) as amount,
       sum(case when a = 'tax2' then b else 0 end) as c
from t
group by column;
```

This does not give exactly the results in your question.  But, the results in your question are unstable because you are mixing `sum(column.b)` with `column.b` -- the unaggregated value is taken from an indeterminate row.

Comment: I think you'll get his results if you use `a <> 'tax1'`

Comment: thank for the tip but the values of column c will be based from column.b where the value of column.b is tax2. is that possible?

Comment: @McFeranco That's what the second `sum()` does.

Comment: Change `a <> 'tax2'` to `a <> tax1` to subtract the first row in each group.